# Page reloads if a second textSearch performed

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps Javascript API to embed a map with the following code:

```
var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(geolocation.latitude, geolocation.longitude);

var mapOptions = { 
    zoom: 13,
    center: loc
};

var mapRequest = {
    location: loc,
    types: ["car_repair"],
    radius: 5000,
    query: "midas"
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapId), mapOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(mapRequest, getMapCallback);
```

Map loads as expected and life is wonderful.

I want a user to be able to change the query parameter and run a search within the same map.

```
mapRequest.query = "honda";
service.textSearch(mapRequest, getMapCallback);
```

When I run the code in the Chrome console, the new search runs as expected. However, when I execute the code above on a button click, the page reloads.
Can someone please explain the inconsistency?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  As a guess, your button click is submitting a form which is causing the page to reload.

Comment: Yes you are right! Do you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can award you as having solved this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your button click is submitting a form which is causing the page to reload.